# Can this stale comment thread be cleaned up?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, comments

[This post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/24435/8816) has a bunch of comments (on the question) that seem to refer to a fight or edit war or something that occurred months ago.  Possibly some comments were later deleted because there seem to be gaps.  Regardless of the history, having all that at the top of the page before you get to the answers is kind of a turn-off.  If the comments should be preserved, can they be moved to a chat thread instead?  What is the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the entire comment thread boiled down to *Don't post LMGTFY links* and wasn't beneficial to the site, I've cleared it. If anyone really wants to see the comments, I can post them.

Comment: I want to see them only if somebody was talking bad of me. `;-)`

Answer (score 7):

You can flag comments, and one of the choices is "obsolete" which would seem to apply here.